SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf How Can I Hide Player Background
I’m developing an application in WPF using SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf for video playback. After the video playback, I want to display an image. However, when I call the Dispose or Stop method in the SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf Player, the FlyleafHost background is displayed momentarily.
How can I prevent the background from being displayed even for a moment after video playback? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
